# How to switch between two text?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How I can switch the text of my button between "Show Comment" and "Hide Comment" whenever I click the button?

```
private void GenerateCommentContent()
{
     var button = new Button();
     button.Text = question.Comment == null ? $"+ {Translator.Buttons_AddComment}" : $"{Translator.Buttons_ShowComment}";
     button.WidthRequest = 100;
     button.Clicked += (sender, e) => OnButtonClicked(commentlabel, frame, button);

        .......
}

    private void OnButtonClicked(Label label, Frame frame, Button button)
    {
        label.IsVisible = !label.IsVisible;
        frame.IsVisible = !frame.IsVisible;
        button.Text = $"{Translator.Buttons_HideComment}";
    }
```

So basically the first GenerateCommentContent will render a dynamic button, label and editor (comment textbox). If the question.Comment is null, the first text of the button is "Add a Comment", but if there is a data, the button should switch to "Hide Comment" and "Show Comment" only every time the button is click.

Comment: This is pretty trivial to do.  What have you tried?  Where specifically are you stuck?  Do you understand how to add an event handler?  Do you understand how to set a Label's text in code?

Comment: here's the docs for the `Button` class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button?view=xamarin-forms look for the `Text` property and the `Clicked` event.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the progress I have. I updated my post of what basically I have right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple bool value to store the current state:

```
private bool commentShown = true;

private void OnButtonClicked(Label label, Frame frame, Button button)
    {
        label.IsVisible = !label.IsVisible;
        frame.IsVisible = !frame.IsVisible;
        commentShown = !commentShown;
        button.Text = commentShown ? $"{Translator.Buttons_HideComment}" : $"{Translator.Buttons_ShowComment}";
    }
```